# What is the issue of this code?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

```
const fs:string = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
File.writeFile(fs, "a.dat",JSON.stringify(A).{append:true}).then(data=>{
//some code here
});
```

it works when append = false but it doesn't work when append = true.
Please help me

Comment: Please edit your question title to something actually about what you're asking. *What is the issue of this code?* is useless to future readers here who see it in a list of search results. Your title should describe the actual problem about which you're asking. While you're at it, be more specific about the problem than *it doesn't work*.

Comment: Actually your question is our question, "What is the issue of this code?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
const fs:string = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
File.removeFile(fs,"a.db").then(data1=>{
File.writeFile(fs, 'a.db', JSON.stringify(A), {append: true}).then(data => {
                            console.log("a.db saved" + JSON.stringify(A));
                        })
                         });
```